# PKCS Library for Safenet 5100

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

```
static string pkcs11LibraryPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\eTPKCS11.dll";    
using (Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(pkcs11LibraryPath, AppType.SingleThreaded))
{
    // Get list of available slots with token present
    List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent);

    // Find first slot with token present
    Slot slot = slots[0];

    // Open RO session
    using (Session session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadWrite))
    {
        session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, "654321");//HSM:123456

        for (int i = 0; i <= slot.GetMechanismList().Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(slot.GetMechanismList()[i].ToString());
        }

        // Prepare attribute template that defines search criteria
        List<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
        //objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, "test"));//HSM:KEY_028_04
        objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));

        // Initialize searching
        session.FindObjectsInit(objectAttributes);

        // Get search results
        List<ObjectHandle> foundObjects = session.FindObjects(2);

        // Terminate searching
        session.FindObjectsFinal();

        ObjectHandle objectHandle = foundObjects[0];

        byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("00000000");
        byte[] inputData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data to encrypt.");


         Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_DES3_CBC, iv);;//HSM: CKM_DES3_CBC

        byte[] result = session.Encrypt(mechanism, objectHandle, inputData);

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(result));
    }
}
```

I got the error `Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common.Pkcs11Exception: 'Method C_EncryptInit returned CKR_KEY_TYPE_INCONSISTENT'` in `byte[] result = session.Encrypt(mechanism, objectHandle, inputData);`

I am using safenet 5100 etoken could you please help?

Comment: You should be able to *get* the *attribute* for the key type of the key you've found. Can you look it up? You may need to compare to a known constant for that.

Comment: Yes I found with CKA.CKA_LABEL, "test" thank you

Comment: The label is not the object type. The type of the object and mechanism must match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are hitting the [most common issue](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/issues/58) and as a result you are using search template which is too broad. With your search template you'll find all objects that have `CKA_TOKEN` set to `CK_TRUE` value. That means all certificates, all asymmetric (e.g. RSA) keys, all symmetric keys (e.g. AES), all data objects and all the other stuff that is stored in your device.

You are then using the first found object (RSA key? AES key? no one knows...) with `CKM_DES3_CBC` mechanism which requires key of type `CKK_DES3` and `C_EncryptInit` functions complains that you have provided incorrect type of key by returning `CKR_KEY_TYPE_INCONSISTENT` error.

If you want to be sure that you will find just 3DES keys than you need to use more specific search template:

```
List<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK_DES3));
```

Even better use `CKA_LABEL` and/or `CKA_ID` to specify exactly one key that you want to use. And don't forget to read at least "Chapter 2 - Scope", "Chapter 6 - General overview" and "Chapter 10 - Objects" of PKCS#11 v2.20 specification.